# Why don't Xamarin.Forms apps work on Chromebooks?

Tags: xamarin, chromebook

I published a Xamarin Forms app to the Play Store a while back. It runs on Android, iOS, and UWP just fine. I see that Chromebooks Chrome OS claims to run Android apps through the store, but when locating my app it says its not compatible. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an exact reason. Does anyone know?

Comment: Does your app require specific hardware capabilities? Such as touchscreen? Which architectures is the app built for? Which Target SDK is it built with?

Comment: Guessing, but is it simply missing-meta data in the app publish (screen sizes, etc) or perhaps configuration on play store about the app?

Comment: Targeted APK - Min Android Version: 5.1 (API 22 Lollipop), Target Android Version: 8.0 (API 26 Oreo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also running in to this issue, try this article here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/

which mentions updating your Android Manifest xml with the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      ... >
<!-- Some Chromebooks don't support touch. Although not essential,
     it's a good idea to explicitly include this declaration. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
              android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

> it says its not compatible.

Chromebooks that are on the market can be ARM **or** Intel based. On the Intel side these range from Celeron 2955U all the way to Core i7s (currently).

Since these x86/x86_64 ARCH/ABIs, you will need to include those ABIs in your apk (or publish multiple ABI-based apks to Play)

Project Options / Build / Android Build / Advanced / Release Configuration:

Select `x86_64` (I do not know of any 32bit x86 only chip being used on Chromebook, but you can include `x86` if needed of course):

[image]